# Custom Contrain Twig

Tags: forms, twig, constraints, symfony

I Have a custom constrain and use it to validate an arrayCollection of entity:

In user Entity i have:

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserFiles", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
* @Assert\All(constraints={  @CustomAssert\FileEmpty })
```

In my twig template where i write `{{ form_errors(form) }}` i see the error as i  want but i don't know how to access to it and write it separately.

In controller i did this:

```
VarDumper::dump($form->getErrors());
```

And the result is:

```
FormErrorIterator {#576 ▼
  -form: Form {#579 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▶]
}
```

How can i access to my error in twig?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem i used a different approach.
I moved the constrains to the userFiles entity property.

My problem was that i didn't know how to access to submitted data in the class validator to make my elaboration.
The solution is:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $userfiles = $this->context->getObject();


        if(!is_null($value))
        {
            if(is_null($userfiles->getFile()))
            {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
            }


        }

    }
```